# How to pass data for partial view using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have next code:

```
@foreach (var offer in Model.Packages)
{
    @Html.Partial("Search/PackageOffer", new Primera.Site.WebUI.Models.ViewModels.Search.PackageOfferViewModel
    {
        Package = offer,
        DisplayPricePerPerson = Model.DisplayPricePerPerson,
        RoomsCount = Model.RoomsCount
    })
}
```

I need to implement infinite scroll using js. How can I call render partial view on js and pass parameters on it?

Comment: You can call your partial view using ajax. It will return the html for you. Then you inject that html at the end of your list.

Comment: @Marco Is it possible without ajax call?

Comment: Possibly, but the web is build around asynchronous javascript, so I would not advise to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Marco So, maybe you have some ideas how to implement infinity scroll in this case? without using partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very basic demo, you want to have a Partial View that is returning some sort of html to you. In my case this is just the next 10 numbers based on the the number submitted:

```
public IActionResult _InfiniteNumbers(int lastId)
{
    var Ids = Enumerable.Range(lastId, 10);
    return PartialView(Ids);
}
```

In a real world scenario this would be the next n entities of whatever - blogs, orderitems, comments.

The view for this is fairly straight forward as well:

```
@model IEnumerable<int>

@foreach (var number in Model)
{
    <li data-number="@number">@number</li>
}
```

it just renders every number as a list item.

My main view then looks like this:

```
<h1>InfiniteNumbers</h1>
<ul id="partial-view-container">

</ul>
<input id="btnLoadMore" type="button" name="loadMore" value="Load More numbers" />

    @section scripts {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(() => {
                $("#btnLoadMore").click(() => { //the trigger
                    var ul = $("#partial-view-container"); //our container for all partial views
                    let lastId = 0; //the lastId displayed
                    let lastLi = $("#partial-view-container li:last-child"); //find the last number
                    if (lastLi.length !== 0) { 
                        lastId = lastLi.attr("data-number"); //if we found something set the value
                        //lastId = +lastLi.data("number");
                    }
                    $.get(`/Home/_InfiniteNumbers?lastId=${lastId}`) //call our action method
                        .then((res) => {
                            ul.append(res); //append the html to the container
                        });
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

We have a `<ul></ul>` element that serves as our container for infinite loading. Since I am lazy, I am using a button as the trigger. In a more complex scenario, this would be an event waiting for the scrollbar to reach the bottom of the page or something similar. I'll leave this up to you.

We then query the list for its last `<li>` item and get its `data-number` attribute. 
After this, we query our action method and get the next 10 items based on that number and finally just inject them into our view.